# Can eating more fats, carbohydrates and sugar improve mood?

Tags: depression, psychiatrist-psychiatry, carbohydrates

There seems to be a lot of research cautioning people with anxiety and depressive disorders to limit their intake of refined carbohydrates, sugars and fats. A person who has suffered dysthymia and anhedonia for many years has tenuously observed that eating lots of sugar, fat like whipped cream and refined carbs is alleviating their condition. Is there any research supporting this?

Comment: Update on this: I don't think sugar or carbohydrates help but increasing fat most certainly did.